# Corresponding arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So let's say I have two arrays

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var y = [A,B,C,D,E,F]
```

I want to display the values of the variables together based on their index location/value. eg: so A corresponds with 1, B corresponds with 2, etc, like so:

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
etc
```

How can I display them together based on their index location?

Comment: Look for a `zip` function.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: What? As posted, your second array is an array of variables. If they haven't been declared, the JS fails gracefully. What is the first array supposed to be? Can't be the values for the second array. Indices for second array? No, you know that from the second array. Please don't use examples that contain data that is ambiguous - declaring an array with values `var x = [17, 5, 2, 1028, 20, 0]` and an explanation would have told us more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming they always match, just loop one and reference both:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(y[i] + "," + x[i]);
}
```